# Can't grab two fields from a webpage in desired way

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I've created a script in python to fetch two fields (2nd and 3rd columns) `time` and `currency` from a table located in a webpage. The script is grabbing the results but not the way I wish that to.

[Website address](https://www.forexfactory.com/calendar.php?week=this)

I've written so far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://www.forexfactory.com/calendar.php?week=this"

res = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")

for item in soup.select("tr.calendar_row"):
    ftime = item.select_one("td.calendar__time").get_text(strip=True)
    currency = item.select_one("td.calendar__currency").get_text(strip=True)
    print(ftime,currency)
```

Results I'm having:

```
All Day JPY
5:00am CNY
 CNY
2:00pm USD
1:59am JPY
2:00am EUR
 EUR
4:30am GBP
 GBP
 GBP
```

Expected results:

```
All Day JPY
3:00pm CNY
3:00pm CNY
2:00pm USD
1:59am JPY
12:00pm EUR
12:00pm EUR
2:30pm GBP
2:30pm GBP
2:30pm GBP
```

> The ***times*** I'm getting are different from that site. Moreover, I wish to fill in the ***blank times*** with its ***earlier values***.

***How can I modify my existing script to fetch the results that I've shown above?***

Comment: you have to remeber time from previous row and fill empty space using this information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem is with empty cells in time column

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://www.forexfactory.com/calendar.php?week=this"

# Make cookie dictionary for setting timezones
cookies={
    "fftimezoneoffset":"0", #timezone / UTC +/-X
    "fftimeformat":"1", # format 0=am/pm / 1=24hour format
    "ffdstonoff":"1", # daylight saving
    "ffverifytimes":"1" # set times to timezone
}
res = requests.get(URL,cookies=cookies) # apply timezones
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
lastTime = "" #lastTime for cases with empty values for times
for item in soup.select("tr.calendar_row"):

    ftime = item.select_one("td.calendar__time").get_text(strip=True)
    if len(ftime) == 0: #if empty time use last one 
        ftime = lastTime
    lastTime = ftime
    currency = item.select_one("td.calendar__currency").get_text(strip=True)
    if len(currency) > 0: # print if there is currenty 
        print(ftime,currency)
```

Comment: Yes, that perfectly fills in the blank columns. However, `the time I'm still having different` from how it is in that site like the way you can see in my expected output..

Comment: For that you would have to use cookies with certain values for you timezone

Comment: @MITHU added way to set timezones

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted to achieve. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can append data inside an object and store the previous values in case of missing:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://www.forexfactory.com/calendar.php?week=this"

res = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")

results = []
for item in soup.select("tr.calendar_row"):
    day = item.select_one("td.calendar__date").get_text(strip=True)
    ftime = item.select_one("td.calendar__time").get_text(strip=True)
    currency = item.select_one("td.calendar__currency").get_text(strip=True)
    print(ftime, currency)
    if not ftime:
        ftime = previoustime
    if not day:
        day = previousday
    if currency:
        results.append(
                {
                'day': day,
                'time': ftime,
                'cur': currency
                }
        )
    previoustime = ftime
    previousday = day

from pprint import pprint
pprint(results)
```

**RESULTS:**

```
[{'cur': 'JPY', 'day': 'SunAug 11', 'time': 'All Day'},
 {'cur': 'CNY', 'day': 'MonAug 12', 'time': '5:00am'},
 {'cur': 'CNY', 'day': 'MonAug 12', 'time': '5:00am'},
 {'cur': 'USD', 'day': 'MonAug 12', 'time': '2:00pm'},
 {'cur': 'NZD', 'day': 'MonAug 12', 'time': '6:45pm'},
 {'cur': 'AUD', 'day': 'MonAug 12', 'time': '6:50pm'},
 {'cur': 'JPY', 'day': 'MonAug 12', 'time': '7:50pm'},
 {'cur': 'AUD', 'day': 'MonAug 12', 'time': '9:30pm'},
 {'cur': 'CNY', 'day': 'MonAug 12', 'time': '10:11pm'},
 {'cur': 'JPY', 'day': 'TueAug 13', 'time': '12:30am'},
 {'cur': 'JPY', 'day': 'TueAug 13', 'time': '1:59am'},
 {'cur': 'EUR', 'day': 'TueAug 13', 'time': '2:00am'},
 {'cur': 'EUR', 'day': 'TueAug 13', 'time': '2:00am'},
 {'cur': 'GBP', 'day': 'TueAug 13', 'time': '4:30am'},
 {'cur': 'GBP', 'day': 'TueAug 13', 'time': '4:30am'},
 {'cur': 'GBP', 'day': 'TueAug 13', 'time': '4:30am'},
 {'cur': 'EUR', 'day': 'TueAug 13', 'time': '5:00am'},
 {'cur': 'EUR', 'day': 'TueAug 13', 'time': '5:00am'},
 {'cur': 'GBP', 'day': 'TueAug 13', 'time': '5:35am'},
 {'cur': 'USD', 'day': 'TueAug 13', 'time': '6:00am'},
 {'cur': 'USD', 'day': 'TueAug 13', 'time': '8:30am'},
 {'cur': 'USD', 'day': 'TueAug 13', 'time': '8:30am'},
 {'cur': 'GBP', 'day': 'TueAug 13', 'time': '9:30am'},
 {'cur': 'JPY', 'day': 'TueAug 13', 'time': '7:50pm'},
 {'cur': 'AUD', 'day': 'TueAug 13', 'time': '8:30pm'},
 {'cur': 'AUD', 'day': 'TueAug 13', 'time': '9:30pm'},
 {'cur': 'CNY', 'day': 'TueAug 13', 'time': '10:00pm'},
 {'cur': 'CNY', 'day': 'TueAug 13', 'time': '10:00pm'},
 {'cur': 'CNY', 'day': 'TueAug 13', 'time': '10:00pm'},
 {'cur': 'CNY', 'day': 'TueAug 13', 'time': '10:00pm'},
 {'cur': 'EUR', 'day': 'WedAug 14', 'time': '2:00am'},
 {'cur': 'EUR', 'day': 'WedAug 14', 'time': '2:45am'},
 {'cur': 'AUD', 'day': 'WedAug 14', 'time': '3:30am'},
 {'cur': 'GBP', 'day': 'WedAug 14', 'time': '4:30am'},
 {'cur': 'GBP', 'day': 'WedAug 14', 'time': '4:30am'},
 {'cur': 'GBP', 'day': 'WedAug 14', 'time': '4:30am'},
 {'cur': 'GBP', 'day': 'WedAug 14', 'time': '4:30am'},
 {'cur': 'GBP', 'day': 'WedAug 14', 'time': '4:30am'},
 {'cur': 'GBP', 'day': 'WedAug 14', 'time': '4:30am'},
 {'cur': 'EUR', 'day': 'WedAug 14', 'time': '5:00am'},
 {'cur': 'EUR', 'day': 'WedAug 14', 'time': '5:00am'},
 {'cur': 'EUR', 'day': 'WedAug 14', 'time': '5:00am'},
 {'cur': 'EUR', 'day': 'WedAug 14', 'time': 'Tentative'},
 {'cur': 'USD', 'day': 'WedAug 14', 'time': '8:30am'},
 {'cur': 'USD', 'day': 'WedAug 14', 'time': '14th-18th'},
 {'cur': 'USD', 'day': 'WedAug 14', 'time': '10:30am'},
 {'cur': 'AUD', 'day': 'WedAug 14', 'time': '7:00pm'},
 {'cur': 'AUD', 'day': 'WedAug 14', 'time': '9:00pm'},
 {'cur': 'AUD', 'day': 'WedAug 14', 'time': '9:30pm'},
 {'cur': 'AUD', 'day': 'WedAug 14', 'time': '9:30pm'},
 {'cur': 'JPY', 'day': 'ThuAug 15', 'time': '12:30am'},
 {'cur': 'EUR', 'day': 'ThuAug 15', 'time': 'All Day'},
 {'cur': 'EUR', 'day': 'ThuAug 15', 'time': 'All Day'},
 {'cur': 'CHF', 'day': 'ThuAug 15', 'time': '2:30am'},
 {'cur': 'GBP', 'day': 'ThuAug 15', 'time': '4:30am'},
 {'cur': 'CAD', 'day': 'ThuAug 15', 'time': '8:30am'},
 {'cur': 'USD', 'day': 'ThuAug 15', 'time': '8:30am'},
 {'cur': 'USD', 'day': 'ThuAug 15', 'time': '8:30am'},
 {'cur': 'USD', 'day': 'ThuAug 15', 'time': '8:30am'},
 {'cur': 'USD', 'day': 'ThuAug 15', 'time': '8:30am'},
 {'cur': 'USD', 'day': 'ThuAug 15', 'time': '8:30am'},
 {'cur': 'USD', 'day': 'ThuAug 15', 'time': '8:30am'},
 {'cur': 'USD', 'day': 'ThuAug 15', 'time': '8:30am'},
 {'cur': 'USD', 'day': 'ThuAug 15', 'time': '9:15am'},
 {'cur': 'USD', 'day': 'ThuAug 15', 'time': '9:15am'},
 {'cur': 'USD', 'day': 'ThuAug 15', 'time': '10:00am'},
 {'cur': 'USD', 'day': 'ThuAug 15', 'time': '10:00am'},
 {'cur': 'USD', 'day': 'ThuAug 15', 'time': '10:30am'},
 {'cur': 'USD', 'day': 'ThuAug 15', 'time': '4:00pm'},
 {'cur': 'NZD', 'day': 'ThuAug 15', 'time': '6:30pm'},
 {'cur': 'EUR', 'day': 'FriAug 16', 'time': '5:00am'},
 {'cur': 'CAD', 'day': 'FriAug 16', 'time': '8:30am'},
 {'cur': 'USD', 'day': 'FriAug 16', 'time': '8:30am'},
 {'cur': 'USD', 'day': 'FriAug 16', 'time': '8:30am'},
 {'cur': 'USD', 'day': 'FriAug 16', 'time': '10:00am'},
 {'cur': 'USD', 'day': 'FriAug 16', 'time': '10:00am'}]
```