# Trouble getting a particular item from a static webpage

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to parse only the `currencies` from a table in a webpage but I'm getting completely different results from that site. The missing `currencies` are available in the `page source`, so thay are static. Where I'm going wrong? [This link](https://www.forexfactory.com/calendar.php?day=today) is different from the one I used in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57479107/cant-grab-two-fields-from-a-webpage-in-desired-way). I thought to mention this for the sake of clarity.

[Site address](https://www.forexfactory.com/calendar.php?day=today)

I've tried:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://www.forexfactory.com/calendar.php?day=today"

res = requests.get(URL,headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'})
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
for item in soup.select("tr.calendar_row"):
    currency = item.select_one("td.calendar__currency").get_text(strip=True)
    print(currency)
```

Output I'm getting (very different from the ones available in that site):

```
JPY
JPY
EUR
EUR
GBP
GBP
GBP
EUR
EUR
GBP
USD
USD
USD
GBP
JPY
AUD
AUD
CNY
CNY
CNY
CNY
```

***How can I get all the currencies from that site using requests?***

Answer (score 1):

The cookies determine some form of validation and thus results you see. You only need two from your other answer. If you omit the second, for example of those shown below, your window shifts to start at 5:30am (Still returning the same number of results) which is the default return - choose any other value for apart from 1, for "ffverifytimes",  and you will get this same window. I assume it is an adjustment to be time aware for the locale for home page?

If you omit "ffdstonoff" your window shifts to 2:30am start.

Add in cookie "fftimezoneoffset":"1"  and you can shift window to start at 11:45pm of day before.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

cookies={ 
    "ffdstonoff":"1", 
    "ffverifytimes":"1"
}
r = requests.get('https://www.forexfactory.com/calendar.php?day=today', cookies = cookies)
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
currencies = [item.text.strip() for item in soup.select('.currency')]
print(currencies)
```

Comment: Did this not answer the question? Is there more info required please?